# How should I test an app build with tornado which uses python 3.5 async?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

This is my handler:

```
class ResourcesHandler(MetaResourceHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    async def post(self):
        arguments = self.get_json_arguments(force_presence=True)
        resources = self._get_collection()

        try:
            resource = await resources.insert({**arguments})
        except Exception as e:
            self._exit_exception_500(e)
        else:
            self.update_response(
                self._prepare_resource({"_id": resource})
            )
            self.finish_request(status_code=http_status.HTTP_201)
```

And this is how I start it:

```
app = tornado.web.Application(('/resources', ResourcesHandler))
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

If I start and try to test with curl it works but, when I'm writing my automated tests with `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase`it hangs forever and raises a timeout. I've already tried to test with pytest-tornado but the behavior is the same.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import unittest

import tornado.testing
import tornado.web

class ResourcesHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        self.set_status(201)
        self.finish('foo')

class Test(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return tornado.web.Application([('/resources', ResourcesHandler)])

    def test(self):
        response = self.fetch('/resources', method='POST', body='')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 201)
        self.assertEqual(response.body, 'Hello, world')

unittest.main()
```

Notice that you don't need "asynchronous" decorator with "async def", Tornado recognizes that coroutines are asynchronous. (That is, it knows that the HTTP response isn't complete until the coroutine exits.)

If your test hangs forever, you may have created the application using a different IOLoop than the AsyncHTTPTestCase's IOLoop? To ensure the application uses the right loop, create it in `get_app`.

Comment: Jesse, thank's for you quick response! However even after applying the changes which you proposed the ```AssertionError: Async operation timed out after 5 seconds``` persists. Would you mind to take a look at my [project](https://github.com/felippemr/resistance)?
Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I've taken a brief look at your project and can't see why your test would deadlock.

Comment: Thank you Jesse! I'll try to find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Jesse's code worked fine to me. If you still have problems, try to update your tornado to lastest version. You can do it just typing:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tornado
```